# Драйвер вебкамеры и средства AForge

Tags: c#, видео

Имеется вебкамера и написанная программа для работы с ней, с использованием AForge.DirectShow (выбор предыдущего разраба). Заметил такую особенность: несмотря на то, что на камеру при установке значения экспозиции (фокус, баланс белого) передается и флаг соответствующий ручному режиму, камера сохраняет режим автоматической настройки экспозиции. Другими словами, когда двигаем ползунок, изображение изменяется, но через некоторое время снова приходит к исходному состоянию. Собственно сам вопрос: как установить режим настройки в ручной, чтоб железно устанавливался?

метод установки:

```
public bool SetCameraProperty(CameraControlProperty property, int value, CameraControlFlags controlFlags);
```

значения CameraControlFlags:

```
public enum CameraControlFlags
{
    /// <summary>
    /// No control flag.
    /// </summary>
    None = 0x0,
    /// <summary>
    /// Auto control Flag.
    /// </summary>
    Auto = 0x0001,
    /// <summary>
    /// Manual control Flag.
    /// </summary>
    Manual = 0x0002
```

отслеживание ссылок по методу привело к такому коду:

```
 [PreserveSig]
    int Set(
        [In] CameraControlProperty Property,
        [In] int lValue,
        [In] CameraControlFlags Flags
        );
```

данный код возвращает код ошибки после попытки установки

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решена: такое поведение вызвано особенностью вебки от Microsoft. У неё есть фича TrueColor, если она включена, все параметры подбираются программно. Отключил через родную программу и все заработало.